# gdata.youtube.service python api : how do i bind it to gdata.youtube.data

Tags: python, api, youtube-api

I'm trying to figure out how to get the Title attribute from the youtube.data object after logging with the youtube.service object. The dblist.dbselectlist() outputs videoids to be concatenated with the uri. any help is appreciated.

here is the code i have so far.

```
import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service
import gdata.youtube.data
import dblist

# Create a client class which will make HTTP requests with Google Docs server.
client = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
# Authenticate using your Google Docs email address and password.
client.email = 'email@outlook.com'
client.password = 'pwdvalue'
client.source = 'my-list-application'
client.developer_key = 'xxxxx'
client.client_id = 'my-list-application'
client.ProgrammaticLogin()

#select all videoids in the rotatevids table
listrotate = dblist.dbselectrotatelist()
for row in listrotate:
        videoid= row["videoid"]
        uri = 'https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/%s?v=2' % (videoid)
        print uri
        video_feed = client.GetYouTubeVideoFeed(uri)
```

when I dir(gdata.youtube.data.VideoEntry) 
it looks like it has the title and text values i'm looking for hopefully

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
video_entry = client.GetYouTubeVideoEntry(video_id=VIDEO_ID)
title = video_entry.title.text
```

btw I think ProgrammaticLogin is deprecated (https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_clientlogin) , you don't need to login anyway, it just needs the developer key.